# Why filter control can't get value date time from repository LookUpEdit?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, filtering

How do filter control get the value from auto filter row?
In the column, I am using RepositoryItemLookUp.

[image: image3]

How can I set filter control hours not 12:00:00 AM instead 09:25:50 AM
or how to set the criteria to equals?

The code I use, was to insert the value to repository lookup..

```
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit rile2 = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit(); 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    rile2.DataSource = dt;
    rile2.PopulateColumns();

    rile2.DisplayMember = dt.Columns["signIn"].ToString();
    rile2.ValueMember = dt.Columns["signIn"].ToString();            
    rile2.Columns["signIn"].FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
    rile2.Columns["signIn"].FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
    rile2.Columns["date"].Visible = false;            
    rile2.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
    rile2.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss tt";
}

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "signIn" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
    {
        e.RepositoryItem = rile2;
    }
}
```